# Is it possible to get a NullReferenceException with a null coalescing operator and a 'as'?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I'm moniterring an application and I got a...

> NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

The Stack trace points accurately to this line of code :

```
 this.ModelControl = this.ModelControl as CreerEtablissementModel ?? new CreerEtablissementModel();
```

Is it possible that `this.ModelControl as CreerEtablissementModel` throw the exception before doing the `??`  ?

#### edit

by request... You'll need this class member (it's inherited in my case)

```
    private const string modelcontrol = "MODELCONTROL";
    public object ModelControl
    {
        get { return (object)HttpContext.Current.Session[modelcontrol] ?? new object(); }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session[modelcontrol] = value; }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your actual code. `this.ModelControl; =` doesn't compile.

Comment: Herp derp, where did that semi-colon came from? ._. (I though you talking about the undefined class member)

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` is likely null or `Session` if session support has been disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible that `as` in combination with the null coalescing operator throws a `NullReferenceException`.

The exception most likely originates from within your property. Either `HttpContext.Current` or `HttpContext.Current.Session` is `null`.

You can easily check this by setting a break point in the getter of the property.